# C Header file being included in another header file and both included in a c file

Tags: c, header, program-entry-point

I have a question regarding header files in C. Let's say I have a header file containing a structure car called `cars.h`, as follows:

```
typedef struct car_s {
    string plate;
    string model;
} car;
```

Now, I have another header file which includes the above header, called `drivers.h`, as follows:

```
#include "cars.h"

typedef struct driver_h
{
    string id;
    string name;
    car own_car;
} driver;
```

Now, let's say I have another file, but this time it is a C file, called `main.c`, as follow:

```
#include "cars.h"
#include "drivers.h"

int main() {
    car c;
    driver bob;
    bob.own_car = c;
    return 0;
}
```

Could you explain why this is wrong and what can I do to prevent any errors?

Thanks!

Comment: First of all, we don't have `string` datatype in a `c` headerfiles

Comment: @VJAYSLN my bad haha I've been studying C# for 6 years and it's the first time I'm studying C and I still make that mistake sometimes, I meant char plate[10];.. and so on

Comment: `person bob;` should be `driver bob;`. I haven't corrected it because maybe it's part of the problem.

Comment: @DavidNagy Yep I noticed that aswell, however this is just code I created this moment to ask the question. I did not use the actual code. Thanks for pointing it out though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that same header file might be included multiple times. What can you do to prevent including same header file multiple times in your code? You can add this in your header files:

For `cars.h`:

```
#ifndef CARS_H
#define CARS_H

typedef struct car_s{
    stringplate;
    string model;
}car;

#endif
```

This will check if this header file is already included, if it is it's not gonna include it again, if not then it's going to be included now.

And you do same for `drivers.h`:

```
#ifndef DRIVERS_H
#define DRIVERS_H

#include "cars.h"
typedef struct driver_h
{
    string id;
    string name;
    car own_car;
} 

#endif
```

Answer (score 2):

The result of including is making one big file for the compiler. Since you already include cars.h in drivers.h, but in you .c file you include cars again, you end up with the file twice included. This will result in the compiler seeing double defintions and, although the same, might complain about this double definition.

One solution is to have so-called "include guards" in your include files that will not make the contents visible if it was included before. Just look up "include guards" with google or on this site.

The better solution would be to be aware of the incldue structure of your module and properly include the files, in this case only drivers.h.

Comment: Even though the answer is correct, I disagree with your last statement. It's not always easy/possible to make sure you are not including the some header file multiple times in a hierarchy. Other than that, I wouldn't rely on that one thing also includes an other (what if the implementation changes?). Of course, in this simple example we can make sure that there's no multiple inclusion and it's clear that `drivers.h` also includes `cars.h`, but I wouldn't rely on it. Just use include guards and include everything that you are intended to use. What are you losing with it?